# Which Function Validates Language Existence: canMatch, canActivate, or resolve?

Tags: angular

If I wish to verify whether the language is both valid and present in the list of available languages, which function should I utilize: `canMatch`, `canActivate`, or `resolve`?

for example:

```
const routes = [
 { path: ':lang', ..., children: [{ path: 'dashboard'... }]}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match is used for ignoring paths and go to the next valid one.

Activate is used to validate access to a path.

Resolve is useless, it should be removed from the framework.

Since you want to VALIDATE a language, you should then use canActivate. If the language exists, allow access, if not, prevent access.

If you use match instead, the route gets ignored, and you go to the next valid one. If there's none, you get a router error. You could maybe use this for a fallback route, but the activate guard does this too, so no point in using it.